# Site Usage Information from Webservice

Tags: workflow, web-services, site-usage

Is it possible to access site collection usage information via web services?

We are looking to get information on last time a site was used so this can be added into a report.  I thought that this information could automatically be populated into a list via a workflow by leveraging web services, but I can't seem to find site usage information.

Answer (score 0):

You could consume [SiteData.GetSite Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms773417(v=office.12).aspx) from [Sites Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sites.aspx) to return site metadata, information about the subsites in the current site collection.

Example

```
var srvSiteData = new SiteDataService.SiteData();
srvSiteData.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

SiteDataService._sSiteMetadata siteMData;
SiteDataService._sWebWithTime[] siteTime;

string users;
string groups;
string[] arrGroups;
srvSiteData.GetSite(out siteMData, out siteTime, out users, out groups, out arrGroups);

Console.WriteLine(siteMData.LastModified); //print Last Modified Date for a site
```

Comment: can be this done via powershell?

Comment: @CodeAbaddon, surely!